# Is there a holomorphic function $f$ around $0$ such that $f(\frac{1}{2n}) = \frac{1}{2n}$ and $f(\frac{1}{2n+1})=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Is there a holomorphic function $f$ around $0$ such that $f(\frac{1}{2n}) = \frac{1}{2n}$ and $f(\frac{1}{2n+1})=0$?

I tried to check the power series, but I couldn't see any pattern. Does that approach even make sense? Or am I missing a simpler/shorter argument?

Comment: Are you assuming $f$ is holomorphic at $0$? If so, the answer is no by the identity theorem. If not, think about the sinc function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Assuming that $f$ is holomorphic in some open disk around $0$, the zeros of $f(z)=z$ have a limit point.

If you are only assuming that $f$ is holomorphic in $0 <|z|<r$ for some $r>0$ then such a  function does exist.